# onClick function fires after clicking twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

For some reason, the onClick will not fire once, but if clicked twice. The `this.props.PostLike(id)` action will be fired, What should i do to make it work only on one click.

Also, the heart state works fine, in just one click. Its just the `this.props.postLike` needs to be clicked twice for it work.

And using `e.preventDefault()` does not solve the issue.

```
    ....
    clickLike = (id) => {
        this.props.postLike(id);
        // toggles between css class
        this.setState({
            heart: !this.state.heart
        })
    }
    render(){
       return(
            <div style={{float:'right', fontSize: '1.5em', color:'tomato'}} >
            <i style={{ marginRight: '140px'}} className={this.state.heart ? 'fa fa-heart':'fa fa-heart-o' }>
                    <span style={{ marginLeft: '6px'}}>
                        <a href="#" onClick={() =>this.clickLike(this.props.like)}>Like</a>   

                    </span>
                    {/* gets the like counts */}
                    <span style={{ marginLeft: '7px'}} >{this.props.likes}  </span>  

                </i>
            </div>       
       )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({

})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({

    postLike: (id) => dispatch( postLike(id))
    // Pass id to the DeletePost functions.
});
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Like);
```

**PostItem.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import moment from 'moment';
import Editable from './Editable';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {UpdatePost, postLike, getCount} from '../actions/';
import Like from './Like';
import Axios from '../Axios';
const Styles = {
    myPaper: {
        margin: '20px 0px',
        padding: '20px'
    },
    button:{
        marginRight:'30px'
    }
}
class PostItem extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            disabled: false,
            myId: 0,
            likes:0
        }
    }


    onUpdate = (id, title) => () => {
        // we need the id so expres knows what post to update, and the title being that only editing the title. 
        if(this.props.myTitle !== null){
            const creds = {
                id, title
            }
            this.props.UpdatePost(creds); 
        }
    }

    render(){
        const {title, id, userId, removePost, createdAt, post_content, username, editForm, isEditing, editChange, myTitle, postUpdate, Likes, clickLike, myLikes} = this.props
        return(
                  ......
                      {/* likes get like counts */}
                       <Like like={id} likes={myLikes} />
                  .......
```

**Posts.js**

```
render() {
        const {loading} = this.state;
        const {myPosts} = this.props
        console.log(this.state.posts);
        if (!this.props.isAuthenticated) {
            return (<Redirect to='/signIn'/>);
        }
        if (loading) {
            return "loading..."
        }
        return (
            <div className="App" style={Styles.wrapper}>
                <h1>Posts</h1>
                {/* <PostList posts={this.state.posts}/> */}
                <div>
                    {this.state.posts.map(post => (
                            <Paper key={post.id} style={Styles.myPaper}>
                                <PostItem myLikes={post.Likes.length} // right here
                                    myTitle={this.state.title} editChange={this.onChange} editForm={this.formEditing} isEditing={this.props.isEditingId === post.id} removePost={this.removePost} {...post}/>
                            </Paper>
                        ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**PostList.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import moment from 'moment';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import {DeletePost, postLike, UpdatePost,EditChange, GetPosts, getCount, DisableButton} from '../actions/';
import PostItem from './PostItem';
import _ from 'lodash';
const Styles = {
    myPaper: {
        margin: '20px 0px',
        padding: '20px'
    }
}
class PostList extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            title: '',
            posts:[],
            loading:true

        }
    } 

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.GetPosts();
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, prevState) {
        let hasNewLike = true;
        if (prevState.posts && prevState.posts.length) {
            for (let index = 0; index < nextProps.myPosts.length; index++) {
                if (nextProps.myPosts[index].Likes.length !== prevState.posts[index].Likes.length) {
                    hasNewLike = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (hasNewLike) {
            this.setState({posts: nextProps.myPosts, loading: false}); // here we are updating the posts state if redux state has updated value of likes
        }
    }
    // Return a new function. Otherwise the DeletePost action will be dispatch each
     // time the Component rerenders.
    removePost = (id) => () => {
        this.props.DeletePost(id);
    }

    onChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            title: e.target.value
        })
    }
    formEditing = (id) => ()=> {;
        this.props.EditChange(id);
    }
    render(){
        const { posts, loading} = this.state;

        // console.log(this.props.posts)
        // console.log(this.props.ourLikes);
        if(loading){
            return "loading..."
        }
        return (
          <div>
            {this.state.posts.map(post => (

              <Paper key={post.id} style={Styles.myPaper}>
                <PostItem
                  myLikes={post.Likes.length} // right here
                  myTitle={this.state.title}
                  editChange={this.onChange}
                  editForm={this.formEditing}
                  isEditing={this.props.isEditingId === post.id}
                  removePost={this.removePost}
                  {...post}

                />
              </Paper>
            ))}
          </div>
        );
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isEditingId: state.post.isEditingId,
    myPosts: state.post.posts, 
})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    // pass creds which can be called anything, but i just call it credentials but it should be called something more 
    // specific.
    GetPosts: () => dispatch(GetPosts()),
    EditChange: (id) => dispatch(EditChange(id)),
    UpdatePost: (creds) => dispatch(UpdatePost(creds)),
    postLike: (id) => dispatch( postLike(id)),
    // Pass id to the DeletePost functions.
    DeletePost: (id) => dispatch(DeletePost(id))
});
// without withRouter componentWillReceiveProps will not work like its supposed too.
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(PostList));
```

Comment: I will make an edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing like that:

```
clickLike = (id) => () => {
    this.props.postLike(id);
    // toggles between css class
    this.setState({
        heart: !this.state.heart
    })
}
<a href="#" onClick={this.clickLike(this.props.like)}>Like</a>
```

Comment: sorry for late reply, this also didn't solve the issue.

Comment: made an update. the like component is within a child component.

Comment: Where do you have access to postLike on Like component? On your code I can't see it as a props

Comment: i made an edit sorry for not including it. The post like is being called for sure.

Comment: Your code seems right, try to add some console.log on your actions to see if it's being called right

Comment: the console.log shows as soon as its clicked, and the backend works on one click. Its just the count thats not updating in on one click, would you like to see the `componentWillReceiveProps` ?

Comment: I saw your code and probably your problem is your way to fetch the posts again.
Everytime that you click on "like" you can dispatch an action that updates your counter, when you did it you can update your local post state (like updating the current list) or you can fetch an API and then get the PostList again. You need to be careful when dispatch this action because you need to update your list everytime that you dispatch the like action. BUT, you can just dispatch the action that triggers the like and if it was successful you can use the setState to upvote the like button.

Comment: Also, try to add your project to github and then use the codesandbox to fetch it
Example: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/github/victorsilent/todo-list-react-redux

How to do: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/YOURUSER/REPOSITORY-NAME

Comment: thank you for sharing the sandbox. Will use this to solve the solution, i accepted your answer for now. thanks.

Comment: Try to paste your sandbox too, will be more easy to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

This likely has little to do with the logic you have set up and more about the html markup itself. If you were to take in the event and console.log it, you'll probably find that you are actually not hitting the  tag on the first click, but one of its outer elements. Try wrapping the  tag and everything else inside of it in a  tag then putting the onClick logic in the button instead and you'll yield better results.

```
     <div style={{float:'right', fontSize: '1.5em', color:'tomato'}} >
        <button onClick={() =>this.clickLike(this.props.like)}>
            <i style={{ marginRight: '140px'}} className={this.state.heart ? 'fa fa-heart':'fa fa-heart-o' }>
                <span style={{ marginLeft: '6px'}}>
                    <a href="#">Like</a>   

                </span>
                {/* gets the like counts */}
                <span style={{ marginLeft: '7px'}} >{this.props.likes}  </span>  

            </i>
          </button>
       div>
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply will try this out. thanks again .

Comment: yeah its doing the same thing. only firing after its clicked twice.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful when using arrow functions with the *this* keyword as it does not refer to the current object, but its parent object instead.

Comment: And this is exactly what the OP would want.?.

Answer (score 0):

```
 clickLike = async(id) => {
    await this.props.postLike(id);
    // toggles between css class
    this.setState({
        heart: !this.state.heart
    })
 }
```

try using the async await

```
  <span style={{ marginLeft: '6px'}} onClick= 
         {()=>this.clickLike(this.props.like)}>
       <a href="#" >Like</a>   
   </span>
```

Comment: sorry for late reply this didn't solve the issue. :(

Comment: thanks for the answer, however the solution did not work. I made an update.